# training my model generates unreasonable loss as well as unreasonable val_loss amount | Loss : nan and Val_Loss : nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

Good morning everyone, I want to ask in this group, I have built a mode from my learning results but I'm having problems in the training section, when I try to train my model it produces los with nonsensical values and val_los which doesn't make sense but on acuracy produces a normal value. this happened when I added a class, in the first experiment with two classes, I managed to do it with 95% accuracy and 93% validation accuracy but after I added 2 classes I received results that didn't make sense, as for some solutions I tried but didn't help me, I've tried to use softmax and categorical_crosscetropy but that doesn't work. when i try to add num_class on dense screen part i get "ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 3) vs (None, 1))". Hope someone can help me . thank you. Here I attach my code

**Load Datashet**

```
training_dir = r"Dataset/train/"
validation_dir = r"Dataset/val/"
testing_dir = r"Dataset/test/"

categories = ['class_A', 'class_B', 'class_C', 'class_D']
```

**Created Data Training**
img_size = (128,128)

```
training_data = []
validation_data = []
testing_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in categories:
        path = os.path.join(training_dir,category)
        class_num = categories.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,img_size) 
                training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
def create_validation_data():
    for category in categories:
        path = os.path.join(validation_dir,category)
        class_num = categories.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,img_size) 
                validation_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
def create_testing_data():
    for category in categories:
        path = os.path.join(testing_dir,category)
        class_num = categories.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,img_size) 
                testing_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
create_training_data()
```

**Normalization of data to range 0-1 and labeling data**

```
X_train = []
Y_train = []
for features,label in training_data:
    X_train.append(features)
    Y_train.append(label)
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1,128,128)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')/255.0  
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,128,128,3)
print(X_train.shape)

X_val = []
Y_val = []
for features,label in validation_data:
    X_val.append(features)
    Y_val.append(label)
X_val = np.array(X_val).reshape(-1,128,128)
X_val = X_val.astype('float32')/255.0  
X_val = X_val.reshape(-1,128,128,3)
print(X_val.shape)

X_test = []
Y_test = []
for features,label in testing_data:
    X_test.append(features)
    Y_test.append(label)
X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1,128,128)
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')/255.0  
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,128,128,3)
print(X_test.shape)
```

**Labeling Data using label encoder for Y_train/val/test**

```
lb = LabelEncoder()
Y_train = lb.fit_transform(Y_train)
Y_val = lb.fit_transform(Y_val)
Y_test = lb.fit_transform(Y_test)
```

**ImageDataGenerator**

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range = 30,
        zoom_range = 0.1,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        horizontal_flip=True,  
        vertical_flip=False)
```

**hyperparameter Tuning**

```
    HP_APL_DROPOUT = hp.HParam('dropout_apl', hp.RealInterval(0.05, 0.1))
    HP_NUM_UNITS = hp.HParam('num_units', hp.Discrete([64, 128]))
    HP_DROPOUT = hp.HParam('dropout', hp.RealInterval(0.25, 0.5))
    HP_OPTIMIZER = hp.HParam('optimizer', hp.Discrete(['adam', 'sgd', 'adamax']))
    
    METRIC_ACCURACY = 'accuracy'
    
    with tf.summary.create_file_writer('logs/hparam_tuning').as_default():
    hp.hparams_config(
    hparams=[HP_APL_DROPOUT, HP_NUM_UNITS, HP_DROPOUT, HP_OPTIMIZER],
    metrics=[hp.Metric(METRIC_ACCURACY, display_name='Accuracy')],
  )
```

**Define Traini Model**

```
def train_test_model(hparams):

  model = Sequential([
      Input(shape=(128,128,3)),

      Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
      BatchNormalization(),
      MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),

      Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
      BatchNormalization(),
      Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
      MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
      Dropout(hparams[HP_APL_DROPOUT]),

      Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
      BatchNormalization(),
      MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),

      Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
      BatchNormalization(),
      MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
      Dropout(hparams[HP_APL_DROPOUT]),

      Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
      BatchNormalization(),
      MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
      Dropout(0.05),
       
      Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='swish'),
      BatchNormalization(),
      MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
      Dropout(hparams[HP_APL_DROPOUT]),
       
      GlobalMaxPool2D(),
      Flatten(),

      Dense(hparams[HP_NUM_UNITS], activation="swish"),
      Dense(128, activation = 'swish'),
      Dropout(hparams[HP_DROPOUT]),
      Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
      ]
  )
  
  model.compile(
      optimizer=hparams[HP_OPTIMIZER],
      loss='binary_crossentropy',
      metrics=['accuracy'],
  )

  datagen.fit(X_train)
  history = model.fit_generator(
                              datagen.flow(X_train,Y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                              epochs = 5, 
                              validation_data = datagen.flow(X_val,Y_val))
  _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_val, Y_val)
  return accuracy
```

**Running Model**

```
def run(run_dir, hparams):
  with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default():
    hp.hparams(hparams)
    accuracy = train_test_model(hparams)
    tf.summary.scalar(METRIC_ACCURACY, accuracy, step=50)

session_num = 0
for dropout_apl_rate in (HP_APL_DROPOUT.domain.min_value, HP_APL_DROPOUT.domain.max_value):
  for num_units in HP_NUM_UNITS.domain.values:
    for dropout_rate in (HP_DROPOUT.domain.min_value, HP_DROPOUT.domain.max_value):
      for optimizer in HP_OPTIMIZER.domain.values:
        hparams = {
            HP_APL_DROPOUT: dropout_apl_rate,
            HP_NUM_UNITS: num_units,
            HP_DROPOUT: dropout_rate,
            HP_OPTIMIZER: optimizer,
        }
        run_name = "run-%d" % session_num
        print('--- Starting trial: %s' % run_name)
        print({h.name: hparams[h] for h in hparams})
        run('logs/hparam_tuning/' + run_name, hparams)
        session_num += 1
```

**Error Log**

```
--- Starting trial: run-0
{'dropout_apl': 0.05, 'num_units': 64, 'dropout': 0.25, 'optimizer': 'adam'}
C:\anaconda3\envs\sub_base_one\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:1972: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
Epoch 1/5
478/478 [==============================] - 57s 111ms/step - loss: -1034990.9375 - accuracy: 0.3468 - val_loss: -3408716.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.2863
Epoch 2/5
478/478 [==============================] - 52s 109ms/step - loss: -27187870.0000 - accuracy: 0.3779 - val_loss: -70205120.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.3440
Epoch 3/5
478/478 [==============================] - 53s 111ms/step - loss: -159927984.0000 - accuracy: 0.3481 - val_loss: -305764640.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.4137
Epoch 4/5
478/478 [==============================] - 55s 114ms/step - loss: -513765920.0000 - accuracy: 0.3257 - val_loss: -822113920.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.2790
Epoch 5/5
478/478 [==============================] - 54s 113ms/step - loss: -1208896128.0000 - accuracy: 0.3155 - val_loss: -1744491776.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.3015
60/60 [==============================] - 1s 17ms/step - loss: -1766485504.0000 - accuracy: 0.3639
--- Starting trial: run-1
{'dropout_apl': 0.05, 'num_units': 64, 'dropout': 0.25, 'optimizer': 'adamax'}
Epoch 1/5
478/478 [==============================] - 56s 115ms/step - loss: -34721.3828 - accuracy: 0.3015 - val_loss: -56985.7461 - val_accuracy: 0.2465
Epoch 2/5
478/478 [==============================] - 55s 115ms/step - loss: -642847.1875 - accuracy: 0.3482 - val_loss: -1573540.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4442
Epoch 3/5
478/478 [==============================] - 55s 114ms/step - loss: -3433380.0000 - accuracy: 0.4208 - val_loss: -6417029.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.4373
Epoch 4/5
478/478 [==============================] - 55s 115ms/step - loss: -10932957.0000 - accuracy: 0.3973 - val_loss: -16847372.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.3382
Epoch 5/5
478/478 [==============================] - 56s 117ms/step - loss: -26557560.0000 - accuracy: 0.3720 - val_loss: -38307184.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.4483
60/60 [==============================] - 1s 17ms/step - loss: -39560612.0000 - accuracy: 0.4704
--- Starting trial: run-2
{'dropout_apl': 0.05, 'num_units': 64, 'dropout': 0.25, 'optimizer': 'sgd'}
Epoch 1/5
478/478 [==============================] - 56s 114ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.2530 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.2533
Epoch 2/5
478/478 [==============================] - 54s 113ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.2532 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.2533
Epoch 3/5
148/478 [========>.....................] - ETA: 33s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.2544
```

I hope someone can help solve the problem and tell me the cause and solution . Thank you for helping

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: that is my complete code